# Querying Bluetooth Devices android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am new to android and i am stuck. the basic premise for me is, when an app is opened, i need to prompt the user to switch on the bluetooth. and when yes is pressed, i need to begin scanning for nearby devices automatically. one more premise is that i should not use any buttons to start scanning. it should start automatically when the bluetooth is switched on.

The code has no syntax errors. Am i doing something wrong logically?

Because when i run the app, nothing happens. It does prompt to establish bluetooth connection, but after switch on, it should automatically scan and populate the listView in the activity_main file. which is not happening.

the activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shashineha.mybluetoothapp.MainActivity">

     <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/listView_Bluetooth"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the mainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.bluetooth.bluetoothApp
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.shashineha.mybluetoothapp.R;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_Bluetooth);  
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    bluetoothAdapter.disable();
}

}
```

the androidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bluetooth.mybluetoothapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you declared proper permissions in manifest? Please show us your manifest.

Comment: Also please refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Permissions

Comment: yes. i have declared the permissions in the manifest. updated with the same. but it still doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you have added these permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

After this, change the condition little bit this way in your `onCreate()`

```
 if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } else {
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
```

if bluetooth is already turned on, it will simple start scanning which is not happening at the moment. Now it should scan. also note the line

`mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());`

will create null point exception once some device founds. you can first simply check with log message initially. Bind your adapter as it is null in start. Also make sure that you have some Bluetooth devise which can be scanned.